# How to launch 'telnet' console in Android Studio device Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio

I was watching a video where the instructor is using a console to type in commands that lead straight to the Emulated Android device. I have the emulated device functioning and I am using Android Studio, but I cannot seem to figure out where he starts the console from. Any ideas?

NOTE: The video is not public so I cannot link it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. TelNet needs to be enabled in Windows, before you can use it. It is disabled by default I believe. This [site](http://www.itdoescompute.com/2009/10/29/how-to-enable-telnet-in-windows-7/) has step-by-step instructions for enabling it (it works for all versions of Windows - Vista - 7 - 8 - 8.1). Once TelNet CLIENT is enabled:

1. Go to -- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools`
2. <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>RIGHT CLICK</kbd> on an empty space
3. Click `'Open Command Window Here'`
4. Type in `'telnet localhost 5554'` (port of emulated device)

Now you should be connected to the Emulated Android device through TelNet.

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks!  Lots of courses haven't switched over to Android Studio yet, so I never know if it's my PC or my IDE.

Answer (score 6):

On Windows 10

1. In `Ask me anything` type `Cmd`
2. Then `Right mouse button` on `Command Prompt` and `Run as Administrator`
3. Execute this command `dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:TelnetClient` you should get following:

[image]

4. Then type in following `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools`
5. Then type in `telnet localhost 5554` You should get this:

[image]

If not I have failed you....

Hope this saves you some time.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to do this, which might be a little quicker:

1. Enable telnet client on your computer
2. On Android Studio, click the Terminal tab located at the bottom of android studio
3. Type: 'telnet localhost 5554' and you should be connected

Answer (score 0):

**If you are windows user follow this step**

1. go to control panel
2. go to programs and features
3. click on "turn windows feature on or off" a prompt box will be appear()
4. mark the checkbox of Telnet Client
5. open command prompt and type "telnet localhost port_number" (see [cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C25Vw.png) image) after this connection will be establish
6. try out various command like send sms port_number hello, geo fix 14 5 etc